# No module named 'wsgi' on docker

Tags: docker, flask, uwsgi, python-3.8

I'm trying test flask + uwsgi on docker. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8.3-buster as build 
WORKDIR /opt/test_apis
COPY requirements.txt /opt/test_apis
RUN pip3 wheel --no-cache-dir --wheel-dir=/root/wheels -r requirements.txt

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8.3-slim-buster as test_apis_runner
WORKDIR /opt/test_apis
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libpq5 libxml2 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=build /root/wheels /root/wheels 
COPY requirements.txt /opt/test_apis
RUN pip3 install --no-index --find-links=/root/wheels -r requirements.txt
COPY deploy/uwsgi.ini /opt/test_apis
COPY deploy/permission.sh /
COPY flaskr /opt/test_apis/flaskr
ARG uwsgi_uid
ARG uwsgi_gid
RUN bash /permission.sh "${uwsgi_uid}" "${uwsgi_gid}"
ENV PYTHONPATH /opt/test_apis/flaskr
ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi"]
CMD ["--ini", "uwsgi.ini", "--manage-script-name"]
```

here is my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/test_apis.sock
pid = /var/run/uwsgi/test_apis.pid
logto = /var/log/test_apis@(exec://date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log
chdir=/opt/test_apis/flaskr
mount=/=wsgi:app
callable=application
chmod-socket = 664
http-timeout = 120
vacuum = true
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
```

my source code:

```
/opt/test_apis/flaskr
|-__init__.py
|-apis.py
|-wsgi.py
```

command: "docker-compose up" is ok however i got some errors in log file:

```
...
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 8, cores: 15)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 9, cores: 15)
subprocess 6 exited with code 0
mounting wsgi:app on /
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='/') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
mounting wsgi:app on /
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='/') (callable not found or import error)
```

But uwsgi worked when I tried to access to docker and run:

```
$ uwsgi --init uwsgi.ini
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I found solution [here](https://future-architect.github.io/articles/20200513/)

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the linked page is to add

```
chdir = /opt/app/mysite
wsgi-file = mysite/wsgi.py
```

to the uwsgi.ini file. It also worked for me.